# linear programming problem vehicle

Tags: discrete-optimization

I have a problem in which there are 4 ships available to transport people from 3 different bases back to a main base.

1.Vehicle 1 has a capacity of 50, can make 6 round trips and is allowed to visit bases 1 and 2.

2.Vehicle 2 has a capacity of 75, can make 4 round trips and is allowed to visit bases 2 and 3.

3.Vehicle 3 has a capacity of 100, can make 4 round trips and is allowed to visit bases 1 and 3.

4.Vehicle 4 has a capacity of 150, can make 2 round trips and is allowed to visit all 3 bases.

There are 350, 400, 350 people to collect from the 3 bases respectively.

Comment: "split delivery vehicle routing problem"

Comment: Does your given set of routes specify the number of passengers from each base?  What are your decision variables?

Comment: That decision variable will not suffice because the numbers of people from each base can be different for each round trip of that same ship and route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_b$ be the number of people at base $b$.  Let $c_i$ be the capacity of ship $i$.

Let binary decision variable $x_{ijk}$ indicate whether ship $i$ uses route $j$ in trip $k$.  Let nonnegative integer decision variable $y_{ijkb}$ be the number of people served at base $b$ on that trip.

The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j,k} d_j x_{ijk}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j,k} y_{ijkb} &\ge p_b &&\text{for all $b$} \tag1 \\
\sum_b y_{ijkb} &\le c_i x_{ijk} &&\text{for all $i,j,k$} \tag2 \\
\sum_j x_{ijk} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i,k$} \tag3
\end{align}

Constraint $(1)$ covers all people at base $b$.  Constraint $(2)$ enforces both the capacity of ship $i$ and the logical implication $y_{ijkb} > 0 \implies x_{ijk} = 1$.  Constraint $(3)$ enforces at most one route per ship and trip.